# Multi-theme (nginx server) specific theme css, js not loading

Tags: magento2

Very strange issue, one specific (multi-store) theme css and js are not loading. The server is "nginx". I run multiple times below static-content command.

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Test/testdealer en_US -f

Other stores are working fine except Test/testdealer

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If multi-stores, then please define the correct language "locale", while running static-content deploy command.

Please verify the store "locale" via:

admin->stores->configuration->select store-view->general->general->locale options->locale (store view)...

If locale is "English (Australia)", then static-content command must be:

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Test/testdealer en_AU -f

Thanks,